# C#で自作ブラウザ　JavaScript対応について

Tags: c#

C#にあるコントロールの`WebBrowser`を使って自作ブラウザを作成しようと考えています。
JavaScriptを用いたページに対応させるためにJavaScriptエンジンを組み込もうと考えているのですが、
どのような方法があるでしょうか？

Comment: 余談ですがChromeやSafari、Firefox(と同じ機能)を代わりに使うにはどうすればいいのかという質問が[英語でやりとり](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome)されており、Geckoについては[geckofx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx)、WebKitについては[WebKit-Sharp](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp)が紹介されていました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

わざわざ組み込む必要もなく、デフォルトでWebBrowserコントロールは、
InternetExplorerを使用しているので、対応しています。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございました。